# Prevent Kafka broker from closing idle connection

Tags: apache-kafka

In my case, my producer uses librdkafka, `topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms` is by default 5mins. 
On broker side `connections.max.idle.ms` is 2 hours, we have pretty low qps, but We want 99.9% of request within rtt 20ms, but if the broker close the connection, the producer will re-establish the channel and send the message, which will get a high latency. It seems the metadata refresh won't work.

How do I address this problem?

Comment: It seems high latency or it is high latency? Do you have numbers on how long connection reestablishment is taking?

Answer (score 1):

For each metadata refresh librdkafka will pick a suitable broker connection to send the request on, it will not send on all broker connections and it will not send on a truly random connection, so the topic metadata refresh can't be used to keep all connections alive.

The Kafka protocol does not really have a cheap or side-effect free way of "heartbeating" (not to be confused with the HeartbeatRequest) an idle connection.

With broker >=v0.11 it is possible to send a Metadata request for the cluster information only (not requesting any topics, thus cheap).
I suggest creating a feature request github issue for librdkafka if this is something you want.

But if you don't want idle connections reaped, why not set connections.max.idle.ms really high?