# are there heartbeats/keep alive messages between Kafka Producer and Kafka broker during idling periods?

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka

I know Kafka Consumer and broker exchange Heartbeat messages during idling(application messages not sent) periods (governed by heartbeat.interval.ms in librdkafka).
Is similar heartbeat messaging scheme used between Kafka Producer and Broker ?
If **yes**,

- what are the contents of such heartbeat TCP packet? or is it a TCP packet without payload ?
- in librdkafka what is the configuration that controls heartbeat interval and maximum allowed heartbeat miss count ?

If **NO**,

- some firewall rules break idling TCP connections. How can such a situation be handled ? Is there a mechanism to send a message from producer without it being written on topic ?

EDIT:
As per related question
[Prevent Kafka broker from closing idle connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484326/prevent-kafka-broker-from-closing-idle-connection), Author of librdkafka says "The Kafka protocol does not really have a cheap or side-effect free way of "heartbeating" (not to be confused with the HeartbeatRequest) an idle connection." in 2017.

But librdkafka has property socket.keepalive.enable (Enable TCP keep-alives (SO_KEEPALIVE) on broker sockets).
Which seems to be added before 2017 (in 2015) as per https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/issues/283

Comment: It is TCP, but why do you need to know the packet structure? You could use Wireguard to watch traffic on port 9092, if you really want to look. Producers don't really need a heartbeat since they don't coordinate leadership groups like consumers do, and no, producers must write to topics. Sounds like you're asking for AdminClient or metadata requests

Comment: @OneCricketeer, seems what you are saying is NO Heartbeats between Producer and Broker. If so, is there anything that can be done from Application side to avoid firewall breaking the Idle connection ? There are Non-Fatal errors thrown due to these disconnects.

Comment: As mentioned, the producer sends metadata requests for the partition count every 5 minutes, by default (`metadata.max.age.ms`) to configure the partitioner logic. These aren't exactly "heartbeats"